Data factory: polybase option missing from copy method
PolyBase options is missing
I'm currently taking a Data Factory class. In the current lab we're working with different copy methods in the sink section. I started with Bulk insert and moved on to Copy command. I'm now ready to move on to PolyBase but the option is gone.
I've been searching but can’t find a solution to make the PolyBase option reappear. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

What type of sink do you use? It would help if you share a screenshot.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@kepp To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

I have the same issue when working on Copy multiple tables in bulk by using Azure Data Factory in the Azure portal official article from Microsoft. Step 7d of Create the pipeline IterateAndCopySQLTables reads For Copy method, select PolyBase.. But that option not there. As referenced by @Bhavani, it seems “Polybase” and the “COPY command” are only applicable to Azure Synapse Analytics.

Microsoft team should make correction at articles (like the one I referenced above) related to Azure Data Factory.

According to this

Polybase” and the “COPY command” are only applicable to Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure SQL Data Warehouse) as sink.


That may be reason for that you are not find in  Polybase option for your copy activity. Along with that follow below configurations:

If your source data is in Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 or Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 then Polybase copy method is compatible.

The  source data format  is of  Parquet,  ORC, or  Delimited text, with the following configurations:

Folder path doesn't contain wildcard filter.
File name is empty, or points to a single file. If you specify wildcard file name in copy activity, it can only be  *  or  *.*.
rowDelimiter  is  default,  \n,  \r\n, or  \r.
nullValue  is left as default or set to  empty string  (""), and  treatEmptyAsNull  is left as default or set to true.
encodingName  is left as default or set to  utf-8.
quoteChar,  escapeChar, and  skipLineCount  aren't specified. PolyBase support skip header row, which can be configured as  firstRowAsHeader.
compression  can be  no compression,  GZip, or  Deflate.



For more information you can refer the below documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#use-polybase-to-load-data-into-azure-synapse-analytics

Data Factory: PolyBase Option Missing Copy Method (devcodef1.com)



@kepp Please check if the solution helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
